# Trying to access server side variable from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

i have a page where in the form load i initialize a server side variable with value and i want to render that value in js section. i am working with asp.net webform apps.

### my server side page load code

```
 string errblankEmail ="";
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    errblankEmail ="Hello World";
 }

if (str == '') {
  alert('<% =errblankEmail %>');
}
```

when i run the page then i am getting error message like
**CS0103: The name 'errblankEmail' does not exist in the current context**

and i also saw that my page_load is not getting called because i set break point there.
so guide me how to fix this problem. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make the variable `public` in order to access it.

```
public string errblankEmail ="";
```